# Shareable link for Google Drive file

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api, sharing

How can I get a link to a file on Google Drive (GTLDriveFile) that I can share in the social networks? How do you do that? `alternateLink` is not what I need.

Comment: Search the sample code for `GTLDriveFileExportLinks`.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for the answer but I don't quite get you. Do you mean search in Google? I haven't found anything unfortunately. I looked at this class and it is very small, nothing helpful. Can you please tell me a bit more?

Comment: [Google's sample code.](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Examples/DriveSample/)

Comment: @rmaddy ok, GTLDriveFileExportLinks is there. But for my files the property exportLinks is always nil even if a file has been shared on Google Drive. Can you please give me some more information?